# Need to add a caption to a jpg, python can't find the image

Tags: python, image

I am trying to add a caption - the file name - under the bottom edge of a jpg.

I have the following Python code:

```
    import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, os, glob

list = glob.glob('*.jpg')

for infile in list:
    print infile
    file, ext = os.path.splitext(infile)
    outname = file + "_test.jpg"
    print outname
    im = Image.open(infile)
    d = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    f = ImageFont.truetype("Arial.ttf", 16)
    d.text((4,0), file, font=f)
    im.save(outname)
```

It prints out the name of the file, so the file is there - so why can't it open it?

The file exists, but I get the following error:
[image]

Is there an easier way to add a caption to the bottom of the image?

Comment: try using fully qualified names.

Comment: If you were on anything but windows, I'd recommend convert, the ImageMagick tool. For example: convert -pointsize 14 -fill black -draw 'text 10,460 "This is a caption" ' image.jpg image_out.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You can use either a string (representing the filename) or a file object as the file argument. In the latter case, the file object must implement read, seek, and tell methods, and be opened in binary mode."

Try this:

```
im = Image.open(open(infile, 'rb'))
```

or:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
im = Image.open(StringIO(infile))
```

Comment: Nope, that gets the same error. I am wondering if I have a hidden char in there somewhere - I'll try retyping the code and see if that works...BTW, why two open's?

Comment: OK, that makes sense re the binary load.

Comment: I just added the following imports, and it worked (after I commented out the last 4 lines): from PIL import Image & import glob, os, Tkinter, ImageTk,fnmatch - so it wasn't the file itself, but something to do with the read...I'll play with including each line in turn, see where it actually fails.

Comment: The second open, open(infile, 'rb'), opens the file for read in binary mode and returns a file object.

Comment: OK, using the open, open(infile, rb) worked to get it to run until the f = ImageFont.truetype("Arial.ttf", 16) line...it couldn't find the resource...I assume it means the Arial font...which should be a standard font, right?

Comment: If you don't have the font file "Arial.ttf" in the current directory, you have to specify the absolut path to the font.

Comment: On Windows, if the given file name does not exist, the loader also looks in Windows fonts directory. But, in the case it doesn't work, try to load the default font with ImageFont.load_default()

Comment: OK...question due to brain freeze - where do I find the path to the fonts?

Comment: I think in Windows is in %windir%\fonts

Comment: I'll try that. I did go to CP and found the fonts and just copied the Arial font files to the folder, and it worked! It did put it at the top inside the image, but that could work...may need to use a larger than 16 font to be readable in the thumbnail though. Anyway, thanks for the help to you and Nick - this is a good place to quit for the night...

Answer (score 0):

That exception, `Cannot identify image file`, means that it was able to open the file, but then could not determine what type of image it is. PIL does this by reading the first 16 bytes and seeing if they match any of the well known [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29).

Could you verify that the file you're trying to read is actually a jpeg?

If so, how did you get the version of PIL? If it was compiled on a machine without libjpeg (or whatever the windows equivalent is), it might not support jpegs. See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891091/how-to-install-pil-package-with-jpeg-support-in-windows) for a possible solution to that issue, though I don't have a windows machine to test with.

Comment: I can read it with another similar PIL code that was just reading the file - I had the generic PIL & got a message on this the a C module was needed so I installed PILLOW...that got past the C error but then I get this. PILLOW is supposed to fill in the JPG gap in PIL. Since this has the same code up to and including the open(), not sure why this isn't working. I just tested to other code (which has no caption ability) and it is working fine reading the entire folder of 471 jpg files...

Comment: See the answers below - it was a combination of needing some imports and a direct line to the font. Thanks to both of you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of Nick & Manu pointing me in the right dierction, I worked out a solution that works:

```
    import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
from PIL import Image
import glob, os
import Tkinter
import ImageTk
import fnmatch

list = glob.glob('*.jpg')

cnt = 0
for infile in list:
    cnt += 1
    print infile
    file, ext = os.path.splitext(infile)
    outname = file + "_test.jpg"
    print outname
    #im = Image.open(infile)
    im = Image.open(open(infile, 'rb'))
    d = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    f = ImageFont.truetype("c:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf", 200)
    x = 10
    y = 550
    d.text((x, y), str(cnt), font=f)
    im.save(outname)
    print "==========="
```

Note that this uses the direct path to the font, and I set the x, y location on the image.

I also had to use a very large font size since the original file is a very large full image from the camera.

I used the cnt as a string for continuity - the originals have a number of names.

All I need to do now is locate the bottom of the image and place the string there...